# Why my post dall does not get data in MVC and Angular 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-web-api, angular6, angular7

i have below code i want to post data from angular to Asp.net MVC but in object its null. method was call but parameter was null any idea why ??

ANGULAR

```
 var result =  { SearchText: "PARK"};
this.httpClient.post(
'http://localhost:55063/Common/PostAddress',result
).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
              console.log(res);
              this.data = res;
            });
```

MVC

```
 public class CommonController : Controller
    {
        protected SCommon sCommon = null;
        public async Task<ActionResult> PostAddress(RoleModel Id)
        {
            sCommon = new SCommon();
            var User = await sCommon.GetAddress(Id.SearchText).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return Json(User, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }

    public class RoleModel
    {
        public string SearchText { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding header to your post and stringify your body

```
     const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Content-Type": "application/json"

          })
        };

      var result =  { SearchText: "PARK"};  
 const body = JSON.stringify(result);
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:55063/Common/PostAddress',body,httpOptions).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.data = res;
        });
```

aslo enable cors like this in your Register method

```
 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
```